# Passing different data/color to a canvas element using meteor from the 'click' event of different buttons

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to separate the functions of each button using Meteor. ( example: red button -> make the canvas red, blue button -> make the canvas blue, etc. )

This is what I've tried:

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <main>
    <canvas class='background' width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    <button id='red'>RED</button>
    <button id='blue'>BLUE</button>
    <button id='green'>GREEN</button>

  </main>
</body>
```

**Template.js**

```
Template.body.helpers({
  hello: 'Hi World'
})

Template.body.events({
  'click.red': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#ff0000", "color": "white" });
  }
});
Template.body.events({
  'click.blue': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#0000ff", "color": "white" });
  }
});
Template.body.events({
  'click.green': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#01bf2a", "color": "white" });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `click #red` instead of `click.red`.
The selectors in meteor work similarly like they do ins html-css-js- # for id and . for class.

```
Template.body.events({
  'click #red': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#ff0000", "color": "white" });
  }
});
Template.body.events({
  'click #blue': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#0000ff", "color": "white" });
  }
});
Template.body.events({
  'click. #green': function (e) {
    $('.background').css({ "background-color": "#01bf2a", "color": "white" });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep , this is the solution . Thank you mate . Cheers !

Comment: to make the code sleeker, you can merge all 'click' events into a single Template.body.events block